# ASP.NET MVC 2 server-side validation for ajax form

Tags: ajax, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, webforms, server-side

I've faced the following problem. I'm developing a form for the site and this form should have validation. I wanna to use native ASP.NET MVC 2 validation functionality but get stubborn with it. I have a form that is loaded via $.get and displayed using jQuery UI modal dialog. All examples I found explains how to use MVC validation with simple forms and avoid Ajax forms.

I can enable client side validation for this form, but I need to handle server-side validation correctly. How can I handle server-side validation model errors for ajax forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass your object back to the controller, you have to wrap your code in `If ModelState.IsValid`

Below is a simplified version of how I edit a user.  The first "EDIT" sends the User object TO the View.  The second "EDIT" handles the post from the view.

```
Function Edit() As ActionResult
    ''# do stuff to populate your User
    Return View(User)
End Function

<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
Function Edit(ByVal user as User)
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        ''# do your valid stuff
    Else
        ''# The posted form was not valid, send the user back
        Return View(user)
    End If
End Function
```

Here's the same thing in C#

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    // do stuff to populate your User
    return View(User);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public object Edit(User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            // do your valid stuff
    } else {
        //'# The posted form was not valid, send the user back
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

On your view, if you want to add AJAX validation, just add the following.

```
    <% 
        Html.EnableClientValidation() ''# This is where all the magic happens.  It will build your clientside validation for you out of your MetaData.
        Using Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Users")
    %>

      <!-- all your markup crap -->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.UserName)%></td>
                <td>
                    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
                    <%: Html.ValidationMessage("UserName", "*")%><br />
                </td>
            </tr>

      <!-- somewhere you'll want to add a Validation Summary of all your errors -->
      <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Oops!, please correct the errors...") %>


      <% End Using%>
      <!-- bottom of the page -->

          <script src="../../Assets/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="../../Assets/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="../../Assets/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

## EDIT:

Here is some info on rendering using `Ajax.BeginForm`
http://singulartechnologies.com/asp-net-mvc-ajax-beginform-sample-code
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/02/15/asp-net-mvc-submitting-ajax-form-with-jquery.aspx

Comment: please note, the VB code was run through a converter to get the C# stuff... my C# chops are not what they should be.

Comment: rockinthesixstring, thanks for the response.

This solution works perfectly for none ajax forms, i.e. forms created using Html.BeginForm helper. 

But I use Ajax.BeginForm. And if Model is invalid form is not updated to show errors in validation summary area to a user.

Comment: In your example the form is submitted together with all page contents. It is not the AJAX form. I want that form submit was in ajax without refreshing the whole page (I use Ajax.BeginForm helper's method to build this form) as I display the form in modal dialog and I need to take decision whether to close it or show server-side validation errors to the user.

Comment: Ajax forms are handled the same way, you just send a PartialView instead of a View

Comment: Could you clarify it in a little bit more details? Sorry, I'm rather new to ASP.NET MVC

Comment: I agree with lostaman.  I don't see how your example solves the problem of "submitting an AJAX form".  The part of the problem I can't wrap my head around is that Ajax.BeginForm is used to modify the DOM.  You give it an InsertionMode and an UpdateTargetId.  But when validation fails you are resending the same content that already exists but only replacing part of it resulting in some duplication.  I've tried to illustrate by marking up an example View.  http://screencast.com/t/NjM1MGNlM